# How to repeat Job with Partitioner when data is dynamic with Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to develop a batch process using Spring Batch + Spring Boot (Java config), but I have a problem doing so. I have a software that has a database and a Java API, and I read records from there. The batch process should retrieve all the documents which expiration date is less than a certain date, update the date, and save them again in the same database.

My first approach was reading the records 100 by 100; so the ItemReader retrieve 100 records, I process them 1 by 1, and finally I write them again. In the reader, I put this code:

```
public class DocumentItemReader implements ItemReader<Document> {

    public List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Document read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

        if(documents.isEmpty()) {
            getDocuments(); // This method retrieve 100 documents and store them in "documents" list.
            if(documents.isEmpty()) return null;
        }

        Document doc = documents.get(0);
        documents.remove(0);
        return doc;
    }
}
```

So, with this code, the reader reads from the database until no records are found. When the "getDocuments()" method doesn't retrieve any documents, the List is empty and the reader returns null (so the Job finish). Everything worked fine here.

However, the problem appears if I want to use several threads. In this case, I started using the Partitioner approach instead of Multi-threading. The reason of doing that is because I read from the same database, so if I repeat the full step with several threads, all of them will find the same records, and I cannot use pagination (see below).

Another problem is that database records are updated dynamically, so I cannot use pagination. For example, let's suppose I have 200 records, and all of them are going to expire soon, so the process is going to retrieve them. Now imagine I retrieve 10 with one thread, and before anything else, that thread process one and update it in the same database. The next thread cannot retrieve from 11 to 20 records, as the first record is not going to appear in the search (as it has been processed, its date has been updated, and then it doesn't match the query).

It is a little difficult to understand, and some things may sound strange, but in my project:

- I am forced to use the same database to read and write.
- I can have millions of documents, so I cannot read all the records at the same time. I need to read them 100 by 100, or 500 by 500.
- I need to use several threads.
- I cannot use pagination, as the query to the databse will retrieve different documents each time it is executed.

So, after hours thinking, I think the unique possible solution is to repeat the job until the query retrives no documents. Is this possible? I want to do something like the step does: Do something until null is returned - repeat the job until the query return zero records.

If this is not a good approach, I will appreciate other possible solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: Use partitioning and give each worker a different set of data. This way, each worker can read/update its own data (using pagination or not) without worrying about other threads reading/updating the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a partitioner to your step that will :

1. Select all the ids of the datas that needs to be updated (and other columns if needed)
2. Split them in x (x = gridSize parameter) partitions and write them in temporary file (1 by partition).
3. Register the filename to read in the executionContext

Then your reader is not reading from the database anymore but from the partitioned file.

Seem complicated but it's not that much, here is an example which handle millions of record using JDBC query but it can be easily transposed for your use case :

```
public class JdbcToFilePartitioner implements Partitioner {

    /** number of records by database fetch  */
    private int fetchSize = 100;

    /** working directory */
    private File tmpDir;

    /** limit the number of item to select */
    private Long nbItemMax;

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(final int gridSize) {

        // Create contexts for each parttion
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> executionsContexte = createExecutionsContext(gridSize);

        // Fill partition with ids to handle
        getIdsAndFillPartitionFiles(executionsContexte);

        return executionsContexte;
    }

    /**
     * @param gridSize number of partitions
     * @return map of execution context, one for each partition
     */
    private Map<String, ExecutionContext> createExecutionsContext(final int gridSize) {

        final Map<String, ExecutionContext> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int partitionId = 0; partitionId < gridSize; partitionId++) {
            map.put(String.valueOf(partitionId), createContext(partitionId));
        }

        return map;
    }

    /**
     * @param partitionId id of the partition to create context
     * @return created executionContext
     */
    private ExecutionContext createContext(final int partitionId) {

        final ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();

        String fileName = tmpDir + File.separator + "partition_" + partitionId + ".txt";

        context.put(PartitionerConstantes.ID_GRID.getCode(), partitionId);
        context.put(PartitionerConstantes.FILE_NAME.getCode(), fileName);

        if (contextParameters != null) {
            for (Entry<String, Object> entry : contextParameters.entrySet()) {
                context.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }

        return context;
    }

    private void getIdsAndFillPartitionFiles(final Map<String, ExecutionContext> executionsContexte) {

        List<BufferedWriter> fileWriters = new ArrayList<>();
        try {

            // BufferedWriter for each partition
            for (int i = 0; i < executionsContexte.size(); i++) {
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(executionsContexte.get(String.valueOf(i)).getString(
                        PartitionerConstantes.FILE_NAME.getCode())));
                fileWriters.add(bufferedWriter);
            }

            // Fetching the datas
            ScrollableResults results = runQuery();

            // Get the result and fill the files
            int currentPartition = 0;
            int nbWriting = 0;
            while (results.next()) {
                fileWriters.get(currentPartition).write(results.get(0).toString());
                fileWriters.get(currentPartition).newLine();
                currentPartition++;
                nbWriting++;

                // If we already write on all partitions, we start again
                if (currentPartition >= executionsContexte.size()) {
                    currentPartition = 0;
                }

                // If we reach the max item to read we stop
                if (nbItemMax != null && nbItemMax != 0 && nbWriting >= nbItemMax) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // closing
            results.close();
            session.close();
            for (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter : fileWriters) {
                bufferedWriter.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
            throw new UnexpectedJobExecutionException("Error writing partition file", e);
        }
    }

    private ScrollableResults runQuery() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you. This is definitely the best approach. However, how can I repeat that process? I mean, the partitioner only executes one time. How can I do to execute it in an infinite loop until the query returns no records? Thank you again!